# Writing lines to .csv file fails with command fprintf

Tags: matlab, csv

I want to acces a .csv file, look for empty data blocks and store all of the lines that have no empty data blocks.

This is my code:

```
   filename = 'C:\Users\try.csv'; 
   file1 = fopen(filename);     %Acces file with empty data blocks
   filename2 = 'C:\Users\try_corrected.csv';
   file2 = fopen(filename2);    %Acces destination file

   tline = fgets(file1);        %Read the first line of file1

   while ischar(tline)

       detected = false;
       [r,s] = size(tline);     %Determine the lengt of the textline for the for-loop

       for(i=1: 1: s)
           if( (tline(i)==',' && tline(i+1) ==',') || tline(1)==',' || tline(s-2)==',' )

              detected = true   %Line should not be printed in destination file
              break;

           end
       end

       if detected == false
          fprintf(file2,'%s\n',tline);
       end

       tline = fgets(file1);

  end

  type 'C:\Users\try_corrected.csv'
  fclose(file2);

  textdata = textscan(file1, '%s %f %f %f %s %f %f %f %s %f %s','HeaderLines', 1,'Delimiter',',');
  fclose(file1);
```

If I do the "type" command, I should see all the printed strings which is not the case.
Am I using fprintf wrong? I know there is a command called csvwrite but I thought this could work too?

Comment: Have you checked (add a counter that increments each time you enter that loop, for example), if the `fprintf` section ever gets called? (e.g. if there's an issue with your previous `if` statement it might never actually run).  I'm not sure whether `type` might have problems if you already have the file open, also.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: With "detected = true" without a ; behind it I can see in matlab that this for loop works. 
I also added a control for checking if the "if detected == false" works, I know this is correct. I don't get any errors. I think there is something wrong with fprintf? Ofcourse I also checked the file itself by just opening it, but it's still empty

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question will not help categorize it.  **Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when you open your destination file you need to open it for writing.  Without a second parameter fopen will open for read access. If your destination file did not exist it would return you a -1 file handle.

Use instead:

```
fopen(filename2,'w')
```

Here is a simplified version of your code including that amendment:

```
filename = 'c:\try.csv'; 
fid_in = fopen(filename,'r');     %Access file with empty data blocks
filename2 = 'C:\try_corrected.csv';
fid_out = fopen(filename2,'w');    %Access destination file

while (~feof(fid_in))
    str=fgets(fid_in);
    if (~doublecommas(str))
        fprintf(fid_out,'%s',str);
    end    
end

fclose(fid_in);
fclose(fid_out);

type(filename2)
```

This uses a different method to detect double presence of commas in the CSV line:

```
function flag=doublecommas(str)

    flag=false; % flag = result returned, 
                %        true if empty CSV fields present in line

    if (ischar(str) && length(str)>0)

        for cindex=1:length(str)-1
            if strcmp(str(cindex:(cindex+1)),',,')
                flag=true; break;
            end
        end

    end

return;
```

Comment: I added the 'w' and it works perfect now! Thank you ver much, tiny but important detail that I didn't see... Your code looks more professional but mine works too (for all future readers of this article). I will definitely look at your suggested code! Thanks again